# In Tauri's Wry, how can I intercept the network calls made from inside the webview?

Tags: rust, webview, tauri

I want to read the HTTP network calls that are made while user is inside the webview. How can I do this in Tauri?

Answer (score 0):

As of writing, you can't.

I opened up an issue for this awhile ago: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/4899 . It appears to be a tricky thing to implement, since not all webviews implement support for it.

Comment: Do you know if this can be achieved using only Wry? I went through its docs but couldn't find anything. Wry uses Tao's WindowBuilder but that too didn't have any method to intercept the requests